# How to convert ext4 partition on raid 1 to btrfs?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, ext4, btrfs

I'm trying to convert two ext4 partitions that are on raid 1 with mdadm to btrfs.

When i try to run

```
fsck.ext4 /dev/md0p2
fsck.ext4 /dev/md0p3
```

They return with

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/md0p3 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

But they are already unmounted and lsof shows nothing is running on them.

This is my fstab

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2cbe4ce5-f7f1-4624-b176-5ac0ea3c510a none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-44fbd174:5c5546de:00388295:7ba75fa9-part1 none swap sw 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/91854359-2b38-45b5-b3a8-7dffaea18e34 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /home was on /dev/md0p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-44fbd174:5c5546de:00388295:7ba75fa9-part2 /home ext4 defaults 0 1
# /var was on /dev/md0p3 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-44fbd174:5c5546de:00388295:7ba75fa9-part3 /var ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1A15-0C1A /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

tmpfs           /usr/tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,noatime   0       0
```

Comment: How did you check whether they're mounted or not?

Comment: May be unmounted, but, as part of RAID, it's still in  use. Consider you are trying to operate on one of an **array** of drives.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by booting in recovery mode, removing the mdadm array entry from fstab and then rebooting again in recovery mode. After that I was able to proceed with the conversion.